Getting error while creating OCI function using cloud shell
I am trying to create OCI functions using oci cloud shell but unable to login into docker
Below is the error :
Error response from daemon: Get "https://ord.ocir.io/v2/": unknown: Unauthorized
I have followed all the steps mentioned in Functions QuickStart on Cloud Shell on the doc mentioned below
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Functions/Tasks/functionsquickstartcloudshell.htm#functionsquickstartcloudshell_topic_setup_CloudShell_dev_env_Setup_Fn_Project_CLI_context
I have also tried this command
“docker login ord.ocir.io --username=/oracleidentitycloudservice/”
Ref - https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-login-for-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-is-unauthorized/134294/6
I have selected "GENERIC_X86" in OCI application and the architecture is also same
all the required policies are added as mentioned in the below video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rw-rg5GFJkE
Need solution to this error. Please help me in resolving this error. Are there any prerequisites to use docker in OCI cloud shell
Note : "I have windows machine"

You need to make the connection using
docker login -u '<tenancy-namespace>/<Identity domain>/<user-name>' <region-key>.ocir.io

If you go to your profile - see the screenshot below - you can find the good information to use
docker login -u 'axammtuo5ccy/Default/abc@mail.com' ord.ocir.io

If you are using the Default domain, you can use your username in the profile
docker login -u 'axammtuo5ccy/abc@mail.com' ord.ocir.io

I am updating this answer because, in the documentation, it says

where tenancy-namespace is the auto-generated Object Storage
namespace string of the tenancy in which to create repositories (as
shown on the Tenancy Information page)

It is confusing because you can read tenancy_name; see the second screenshot. In this case, you need to use axammtuo5ccy and not mytenancy
This command does not work
docker login -u 'mytenancy/abc@mail.com' ord.ocir.io



Hope it helps
